# Why does Parfit judge implausible the impersonal average view?

Tags: ethics, antinatalism

Source: Benatar, David. [*Better Never to Have Been*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199549265) (2008 1 edn). pp. 171-172.

> Although the impersonal average view also solves the nonidentity problem, it too cannot be Theory X, for it faces other
>   problems. To show why this is the case, Derek Parfit asks us to
>   imagine another two worlds. In the first world everybody had a
>   very high quality of life. In the second world, in addition to all
>   these people with their same high quality of life there are additional
>   people who, although not quite as well off, nonetheless have lives
>   that are well worth living. These sorts of cases, Derek Parfit calls
>   ‘Mere Addition’. More specifically, mere addition occurs ‘when, in
>   one of two outcomes, there exist extra people (1) who have lives
>   worth living, (2) who affect no one else, and (3) whose existence
>   does not involve social injustice’.²²
>     Now the impersonal average view says that the second world is
>   worse, because **[4.] the average quality of life is lower**. It is made lower
>   by the mere addition of extra people who, although happy, are not
>   quite as happy as the original people are. Derek Parfit takes this
>   to be implausible. It would entail, he says, that **[5.] it would be worse
>   if in addition to Adam and Eve leading blissful lives, there were a
>   billion extra people who lived lives of slightly lower quality**. The
>   impersonal average view also entails, he says, that whether it is
>   wrong to have any given child depends on facts about the quality
>   of all previous lives. Thus, if **[6.]‘the ancient Egyptians had a very high
>   quality of life, it is more likely to be bad to have a child now’**.²³ But,
>   says Professor Parfit, ‘research in Egyptology cannot be relevant to
>   our decision whether to have children.’²⁴ Accordingly, he takes the
>   impersonal average view to be implausible.
>
> ²² Parfit, Derek, *Reasons and Persons*, 420.
>   ²³ Ibid. ²⁴ Ibid.

I acknowledge that most parents nowadays don't mull reproduction that thoroughly, but Parfit's outlook feels wrong to me. How can't a reasonable person:

7. mull (4)-(6) overhead as factors in a decision to reproduce?
8. be dissuaded and thwarted from procreation by (4)-(6)?

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following extract helpful in explaining Parfit's rejection of the impersonal average view. It takes a simple case but this makes the key point more clearly. Page references are to Parfit's Reasons and Persons (1986).

> [First we note] the **Total Principle**, which measures the value of
>    outcomes by summing the net quantities that different persons
>    enjoy in them of "whatever makes life worth living" (p. 387). This
>    view allows the value of an outcome to be improved by the addi-
>    tion of sheer numbers of persons, so long as their lives are at least
>    minimally worth living.
>
> The most discussed alternative to the Total Principle for evaluating outcomes in terms of quality of life has been the **Average
>    Principle**, which awards the prize to the outcome in which the
>    average quality of life is highest. The Average Principle does in-
>    deed avoid the Repugnant Conclusion, for it awards no points for
>    the addition of happy people, unless they are average-raisers. But
>    Parfit quite rightly dismisses the Average Principle as implausible
>    because it has such consequences as that the addition to the world
>    of a person who will have a very good life can make the outcome
>    worse just because other people have lives that are even better (pp.
>    420-422). (Robert Merrihew Adams, 'Should Ethics be More Impersonal? a Critical Notice of Derek Parfit, Reasons and Persons', The Philosophical Review, Vol. 98, No. 4 (Oct., 1989), pp. 439-484 : 472.)

**__________________________________________________________________________**

*Terminology*

> The **Repugnant Conclusion**: For any possible population of at least ten
>    billion people, all with a very high quality of life, there must be some
>    much larger imaginable population whose existence, if other things  are equal, would be better, even though its members have lives that
>    are barely worth living (p. 388).

**______________________________________________________________________**

*References*

Robert Merrihew Adams, 'Should Ethics be More Impersonal? a Critical Notice of Derek Parfit, Reasons and Persons', The Philosophical Review, Vol. 98, No. 4 (Oct., 1989), pp. 439-484.

Derek Parfit, Reasons and Persons,ISBN 10: 019824908X / ISBN 13: 9780198249085
Published by OUP Oxford 1986-01-23, Oxford, 1986.